# Return value from a CorutineExectionHandler to the calling method

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

Is it possible to return value from the CoroutineExceptionHandler to the calling method?

```
 override suspend fun getStatus() : Model {        
return withContext<Model>(Dispatchers.IO + errorHandler) {
                //Do something and return model
                // If any other exception is thrown while multiple coroutines its passed down to errorhanlder
        }
    }


 private val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not.

This kind of handler is for general uncaught exception handling, and can be reused in many different coroutines which may expect different return values, or may not even return a value at all.

If you want to catch some exceptions and return a different value, you'll need to do it right on the spot (for instance around your `withContext`) with a `try/catch` block:

```kotlin
override suspend fun getStatus() : Model = try {
    withContext<Model>(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Do something and return model
    }
} catch(e: Exception) { // use more specific exception if you can
    SomeErrorModel(...)
}
```